# Открытие файла через treeview

Tags: c#

Как при нажатии на текстовый файл в treeview отобразить его содержимое в richtextbox ? Возникает проблема с путём, не могу понять как соединить путь и название выбранного файла.
Как обработать нажатие элемента TreeView?

```
  public string derevo_papok(string path)
        {

             TreeNode tn = new TreeNode();
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("", path,2);
            string[] Directorii = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
            string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            foreach (string s2 in Directorii)
            {
                string t = s2.Substring(s2.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                ((TreeNode)treeView1.Nodes[0]).Nodes.Add(s2, t, 0);
            }
            foreach (string s3 in Files)
            {
                string r = s3.Substring(s3.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                ((TreeNode)treeView1.Nodes[0]).Nodes.Add(s3, r, 0);
        }

                return path;


        }
```

Код самого дерева

Comment: Почитайте о декомпозиции задачи на простые задачи. Ваша задача сводится к (1) обработке нажатия элемента TreeView, (2) чтение и запись дополнительной информации в узел TreeView, (3) чтению содержимого текстового файла, (4) установке контента TichTextBox в заданную строку. Это четыре совершенно не связанных между собой проблемы. Спрашивайте о них по отдельности.

Comment: Тогда вопрос как обработать нажатие элемента TreeView?

Comment: Ну, вы ж уже не новичок на сайте? Тогда вы знаете, что вопросы нужно задавать не в комментариях, а при помощи кнопки «Задать вопрос».

Answer (score 2):

У `TreeView` есть событие `AfterSelect`, возникающее после выбора узла в дереве. В качестве аргумента в обработчик события передается переменная `e`, содержащая в том числе и ссылку на сам узел. Например, можно вывести название узла таким вот образов в обработчике этого события:
`MessageBox.Show(e.Node.Text);`

Таким образом мы решили задачу по отслеживанию выбора элемента `TreeView` через событие `AfterSelect`.

Вообще у элемента дерева `Node` есть свойство `Tag`, в котором можно хранить много чего, но мы попробуем хранить там путь к файлу. Для этого при создании ноды достаточно будет сделать так:

```
string Filename = @"d:\folder\somefile.txt";
NewNode.Tag = Filename;
```

Тогда наш обработчик события будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        string fn = (string)e.Node.Tag;
        if (File.Exists(fn))
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(fn, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
            //или так:
            //richTextBox1.LoadFile(fn);
        }
    }
```

**Обращаю внимание - попытка загрузить файл из текста будет производится при выборе ноды с клавиатуры или одинарным нажатием кнопки мыши.**

Comment: Может я что-то не так сделал, но при выборе файла ничего не происходит.

Comment: А у вас точно назначен обработчик событий для `treeView1` для события `AfterSelect`? И он точно назначен на метод `treeView1_AfterSelect`?

Comment: private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)

Comment: А в обраточике что?
И в вашем методе построения дерева `public string derevo_papok(string path)` вы задаете `tn.Tag`?

Comment: В обработчике то, что вы скинули. Ладно, спасибо за помощь, не буду вас мучать, сам буду разбираться.

Comment: @Андрей, посмотрите еще вот [эту статью](http://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/4.13.php) - там есть примерчик построения дерева папок как в проводнике. Соответственно, можно доделать его под вашу задачку.